# uwsgi: unrecognized option '--module=MyProject.wsgi:application'

Tags: django, uwsgi

I followed the instructions in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/ and it was working fine until a few days ago, when I killed the uwsgi processes and tried to restart again. Then it said

```
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--module=MyProject.wsgi:application'
```

I've been banging my head trying to solve that problem, ... I've checked my commit history and the script I use to start uwsgi hasn't changed :

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/
uwsgi --chdir=/home/MyProject \
    --module=MyProject.wsgi:application \
    --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyProject.settings \
    --master --pidfile=/tmp/MyProject-masted.pid \
    --socket=/home/MyProject.sock \
    --processes=5 \
    --harakiri=20 \
    --limit-as=128 \
    --max-requests=5000 \
    --vacuum \
    --home=/home/MyProject/env \
    --daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/MyProject.log
```

Obviously something must have changed but I cant see what ... I didn't run any update, script didn't change ... PlEaSe HeLp !!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into this recently when I tried to use the version of uWSGI in the Unbuntu 12.04 repo (1.0.3). It looks likes that version is a bit old. Just use pip to grab it (1.2.5).

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Comment: If you want to stick with the Ubuntu version of uwsgi, read the second answer!

Comment: Installing the pip version will kill "sudo service uwsgi start/stop" it will also stop reading from /etc/uwsgi.... So before you do that read the answer below.

Answer (score 41):

You probably need to add the `--plugins` option to your command line to use the system installed uwsgi.  On Fedora 17, at least, this is neccesary for me:

```
$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --module=wsgiref.simple_server:demo_app
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--module=wsgiref.simple_server:demo_app'
getopt_long() error
$
```

but this works:

```
$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --plugins python --module=wsgiref.simple_server:demo_app
*** Starting uWSGI 1.2.4 (64bit) on [Thu Aug 30 14:09:57 2012] ***
[.. snip]
```

Comment: I've found that the ordering of parameters matters. If I try and pass the --wsgi-file parameter before passing --plugins python, it doesn't seem to work. I get a message that says "Unregonized parameter".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
uwsgi --socket /run/uwsgi/mysite.sock --chdir /home/ubuntu/mysite/ --plugin The_OJ.wsgi --chmod-socket=666
```